# Appending to a sequence in Ceylon

Tags: ceylon

How do I append a single element to a list in Ceylon? I tried the `append` method like this, but it only accepts another list:

```
value list = [1,2].append(3); // Integer is not assignable to 'Nothing[]'
```

Obviously, I can work around by wrapping the element:

```
value list = [1,2].append([3]);
```

But I feel there should be a better way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be a Python programmer. The method you are looking for is called `withTrailing`:

```
value list = [1,2].withTrailing(3);
```

Comment: internally `withTrailing(x)` is implemented as `append(singleton(x))` ;)

Comment: @Quintesse Well, FTR, that's the default implementation on `Sequence`. It's actually overridden on `Tuple`. The OP has a tuple.